# Do you have to have a company to sign up for salesforce partner community, or you cam sign up as solo developer?

Tags: isv

Is it possible to sign up to Salesforce Partner Community without having a company?
Can a single developer be an ISV, develop and sell solutions on the AppExchange?
When I tried to sign up to test the water on this whole ISV and Partner Business Org I saw that you have to put in your company's name and legal entity name.
So, how can I sign up for the Partner Community Portal and ask for a PBO without having a company? Is it even possible?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wording of the requirements for becoming a partner strongly suggests that it must be a legal entity. The easiest way to do this is to register an LLC. It takes only a few days or weeks, and a few dollars (typically less than $300) to register an LLC (see [this document](https://www.sba.gov/business-guide/launch-your-business/register-your-business) for more information). Note that the Partner Agreement requires that there be two certificates in the legal entity, either two different developers with one certification each, or one developer with two different certifications.

Answer (score 1):

To join the Salesforce Partner Community, you need a salesforce account associated with your company email address which mean you cannot join the partner community using credentials associated with a personal/individual email such as a Gmail/yahoo etc., address.

[image]

Check [Partner Community User Manual](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000395059&type=1) and [help signing up for partner program](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387087&type=1) for more details .

Answer (score -1):

Salesforce typically requires a legal entity to participate in the program. it is generally required to have a legal business entity or company. Salesforce has specific requirements and guidelines for partner organizations to ensure compliance and accountability within the Partner Program.

Lets wait for more answers on it. Or see if Salesforces provides 'Register as an Individual Developer' for the program.